# CSS browers width

Tags: html, css

My project depend on blocks- if you click href in menu for example "about" site getting you to block with backogrund image. Backgrounds of blocks must adjust to the resolution user. Everythnig work great but if we want to change size browers in width images just unatural distort. I thnink that it is impossible to solve this problem, if we want to stay with:

```
width:100%; 
height:100%;
```

SO How to make divs with bacgrounds image which will adjust to the resolution of widscreen, but if we change size of browers to custom example:365x900 background-image will still in the same resolutions(the same resolution means that size is dependet on the screen resolution)

the best situation will be then when bacground-images will adjust to the standard resolutions, but if we will change browers size for example on 200x900 then they will don't change theirs sizes and still stay in maximum(maximum size is dependent on the screen resolution)

**CSS**

```
#raz {
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: -300px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;        
}

#bg_raz {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

#dwa {  
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;        
}

#bg_dwa {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dwa"> 
    <img id="bg_dwa" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-600-325-4.jpg">
</div>

<div id="raz"> 
    <img id="bg_dwa" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-600-325-7.jpg">
</div>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/46)

Comment: do you want them to scale or always take as much space as possible?

Comment: mmmh the best situation will be then when bacground-images will adjust to the standard resolutions, but if we will change browers size for example on 200x900 then they will don't change theirs sizes and still stay in maximum(maximum size is dependent on the screen resolution)

Comment: Have you tried background-size: cover; ?

Comment: What do you want if size is 200x900 ? #dwa with correct aspect ratio so that it has width "200px"? Or do you want #dwa now got "900px" height and the rest is smth of the middle of the image?!

Comment: @Gorthard: it's a bit difficult to understand what you're saying. What is your actual question?

Comment: nice one, but this change size of image. When we make normal div with some text, and we are changeing browers size the edge cover divs, witohut changeing him

Comment: Sorry I'm trying just explain on examples. Actual question is: How to make divs with bacgrounds image which will adjust to the resolution of widscreen, but if we change size of browers to custom example:365x900 background-image will still in the same resolutions(the same resolution means that size is dependet on the screen resolution)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `background-size: cover;` and add `background-image` on `#dwa`, you can delete `<img/>`.